# Meteor Autoform Select2 set value

Tags: meteor, jquery-select2, meteor-autoform, telescope

I'm using the Meteor autoform select2 package and I'm trying to figure out how to set a selected value. Currently trying the following but then I can't see the rest of the countries list

```
options: function () {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne();
    if (user && !_.isEmpty(user.profile.country)) {
        return {value: user.profile.country};
    }

    return countriesList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always return label & value to selectize options

```
 return { 
         value: user.profile.country , 
         label:"//someName " 
       }
```